# Heroku CLI - how to disable animations and colours

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

The heroku cli for some commands displays a nice looking "loading" animation and colours: `⣟`, `⣯`, `⣷`, ...

In some logging systems, this is not well supported and pollutes them with:

```
[1A[13C⣟[1B[G[2K[1A[13C⣯[1B[G[2K[1A[13C⣷[1B[G[2K[1A[13C⣾[1B[G[2K[1A[13C⣽
```

Is there a way to disable these animations and potentially even colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if the `TERM` env var is set to `dumb` e.g. `TERM=dumb` then download progress is disabled, see:

https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/master/packages/pg-v5/lib/download.js#L9

Perhaps it would be helpful if it was documented.

Comment: Hmm, when paired with other flags, it seems to do the job: `TERM=dumb heroku ps:scale web=1 --no-color --no-tty`. will give it a spin!

Comment: They actually have some mentions of it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cli-style-guide#action-commands